# Stuck in the partial helm release on Terraform to Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to apply a terraform resource (helm_release) to k8s and the apply command is failed half way through.

I checked the pod issue now I need to update some values in the local chart.

Now I'm in a dilemma, where I can't apply the helm_release as the names are in use, and I can't destroy the helm_release since it is not created.

Seems to me the only option is to manually delete the k8s resources that were created by the helm_release chart?

Here is the terraform for helm_release:

```
cat nginx-arm64.tf 

resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" {
  name  = "nginx-ingress"
  chart = "/data/terraform/k8s/nginx-ingress-controller-arm64.tgz"
}
```

BTW: I need to use the local chart as the official chart does not support the ARM64 architecture.
Thanks,

Edit #1:

Here is the list of helm release -> there is no gninx ingress

```
/data/terraform/k8s$ helm list -A
NAME            NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART               APP VERSION
cert-manager    default     1           2021-12-08 20:57:38.979176622 +0000 UTC deployed    cert-manager-v1.5.0 v1.5.0     
/data/terraform/k8s$
```

Here is the describe pod output:

```
$ k describe pod/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-99cddc76b-62nsr
Name:         nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-99cddc76b-62nsr
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ocifreevmalways/10.0.0.189
Start Time:   Wed, 08 Dec 2021 11:11:59 +0000
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress-controller
              helm.sh/chart=nginx-ingress-controller-9.0.9
              pod-template-hash=99cddc76b
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.22
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.22
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-99cddc76b
Containers:
  controller:
    Container ID:  docker://0b75f5f68ef35dfb7dc5b90f9d1c249fad692855159f4e969324fc4e2ee61654
    Image:         docker.io/rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-1.1.0-rancher1
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://rancher/nginx-ingress-controller@sha256:177fb5dc79adcd16cb6c15d6c42cef31988b116cb148845893b6b954d7d593bc
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --default-backend-service=default/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-default-backend
      --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
      --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
      --configmap=default/nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Wed, 08 Dec 2021 22:02:15 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 08 Dec 2021 22:02:15 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  132
    Liveness:       http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-99cddc76b-62nsr (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  default (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-wzqqn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-wzqqn:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Normal   Pulled   8m38s (x132 over 10h)   kubelet  Container image "docker.io/rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-1.1.0-rancher1" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff  3m39s (x3201 over 10h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

The terraform state list shows nothing:

```
/data/terraform/k8s$ t state list
/data/terraform/k8s$
```

Though the terraform.tfstate.backup shows the nginx ingress (I guess that I did run the destroy command in between?):

```
/data/terraform/k8s$ cat terraform.tfstate.backup
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.0.11",
  "serial": 28,
  "lineage": "30e74aa5-9631-f82f-61a2-7bdbd97c2276",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "helm_release",
      "name": "nginx-ingress",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "status": "tainted",
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "atomic": false,
            "chart": "/data/terraform/k8s/nginx-ingress-controller-arm64.tgz",
            "cleanup_on_fail": false,
            "create_namespace": false,
            "dependency_update": false,
            "description": null,
            "devel": null,
            "disable_crd_hooks": false,
            "disable_openapi_validation": false,
            "disable_webhooks": false,
            "force_update": false,
            "id": "nginx-ingress",
            "keyring": null,
            "lint": false,
            "manifest": null,
            "max_history": 0,
            "metadata": [
              {
                "app_version": "1.1.0",
                "chart": "nginx-ingress-controller",
                "name": "nginx-ingress",
                "namespace": "default",
                "revision": 1,
                "values": "{}",
                "version": "9.0.9"
              }
            ],
            "name": "nginx-ingress",
            "namespace": "default",
            "postrender": [],
            "recreate_pods": false,
            "render_subchart_notes": true,
            "replace": false,
            "repository": null,
            "repository_ca_file": null,
            "repository_cert_file": null,
            "repository_key_file": null,
            "repository_password": null,
            "repository_username": null,
            "reset_values": false,
            "reuse_values": false,
            "set": [],
            "set_sensitive": [],
            "skip_crds": false,
            "status": "failed",
            "timeout": 300,
            "values": null,
            "verify": false,
            "version": "9.0.9",
            "wait": true,
            "wait_for_jobs": false
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [],
          "private": "bnVsbA=="
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to apply in the same directory, it prompts the error again:

```
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

helm_release.nginx-ingress: Creating...
╷
│ Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
│ 
│   with helm_release.nginx-ingress,
│   on nginx-arm64.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" {
```

Please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Edit2:

The DEBUG logs show some more clues:

```
2021-12-09T04:30:14.118Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [resourceDiff: nginx-ingress] Release validated: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.118Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.118Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [resourceDiff: nginx-ingress] Done: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.118Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.119Z [WARN]  Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm" produced an invalid plan for helm_release.nginx-ingress, but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
    The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
      - .cleanup_on_fail: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .create_namespace: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .verify: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .recreate_pods: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .render_subchart_notes: planned value cty.True for a non-computed attribute
      - .replace: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .reset_values: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_crd_hooks: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .lint: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .namespace: planned value cty.StringVal("default") for a non-computed attribute
      - .skip_crds: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_webhooks: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .force_update: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .timeout: planned value cty.NumberIntVal(300) for a non-computed attribute
      - .reuse_values: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .dependency_update: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .disable_openapi_validation: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .atomic: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
      - .wait: planned value cty.True for a non-computed attribute
      - .max_history: planned value cty.NumberIntVal(0) for a non-computed attribute
      - .wait_for_jobs: planned value cty.False for a non-computed attribute
helm_release.nginx-ingress: Creating...
2021-12-09T04:30:14.119Z [INFO]  Starting apply for helm_release.nginx-ingress
2021-12-09T04:30:14.119Z [INFO]  Starting apply for helm_release.nginx-ingress
2021-12-09T04:30:14.119Z [DEBUG] helm_release.nginx-ingress: applying the planned Create change
2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] setting computed for "metadata" from ComputedKeys: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [resourceReleaseCreate: nginx-ingress] Started: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [resourceReleaseCreate: nginx-ingress] Getting helm configuration: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [INFO] GetHelmConfiguration start: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] Using kubeconfig: /home/ubuntu/.kube/config: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [INFO] Successfully initialized kubernetes config: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.120Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.121Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [INFO] GetHelmConfiguration success: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.121Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.121Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [resourceReleaseCreate: nginx-ingress] Getting chart: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.121Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.125Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [resourceReleaseCreate: nginx-ingress] Preparing for installation: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.125Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.125Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 ---[ values.yaml ]-----------------------------------
{}: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.125Z
2021-12-09T04:30:14.125Z [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5: 2021/12/09 04:30:14 [DEBUG] [resourceReleaseCreate: nginx-ingress] Installing chart: timestamp=2021-12-09T04:30:14.125Z
╷
│ Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
│ 
│   with helm_release.nginx-ingress,
│   on nginx-arm64.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress" {
│ 
╵
2021-12-09T04:30:14.158Z [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021-12-09T04:30:14.160Z [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm/2.4.1/linux_arm64/terraform-provider-helm_v2.4.1_x5 pid=558800
2021-12-09T04:30:14.160Z [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to manually delete all the resources using `kubectl`. Under the hood the Terraform Helm provider still uses Helm. So if you run `helm list -A` you will see all the Helm releases on your cluster, including the `nginx-ingress` release. Deleting the release is then done via `helm uninstall nginx-ingress -n REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_NAMESPACE`.

Before re-running `terraform apply` do check if the Helm release is still in your Terraform state via `terraform state list` (run this from the same directory as where you run `terraform apply` from). If you don't see `helm_release.nginx-ingress` in that list then it is not in your Terraform state and you can just rerun your `terraform apply`. Else you have to delete it via `terraform state rm helm_release.nginx-ingress` and then you can run `terraform apply` again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and I edit the post with some more information as advised.

Comment: I think I resolved the issue. This is what I did: 1) mv the terraform.tfstate to another name, 2) mv the terraform.tfstate.backup to terraform.tfstate, and 3) run 'terraform refresh' command to confirm the state is synchronized, and 4) run 'terraform apply' to delete/create the resource.  I will mark your reply as the answer, as it gives me the clue for solving the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the 'missing' state was due to the fact that I cancelled the apply command.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced a similar issue like this, but in my case nor there was terraform state for the helm, and nor there was a helm release.
so `helm list -A` or `helm list` in the current namespace does not.

[image]

I found this that solved: [helm/helm#4174](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4174#issuecomment-605485703)

> With Helm 3, all releases metadata are saved as Secrets in the same
> Namespace of the release. If you got "cannot re-use a name that is
> still in use", this means you may need to check some orphan secrets
> and delete them

[image]

and then its start working
[image]